# How to add one day to a date?

Tags: java, datetime

I want to add one day to a particular date. How can I do that?

```
Date dt = new Date();
```

Now I want to add one day to this date.

Comment: FYI: The troublesome old `java.util.Date` class has been supplanted by the `java.time.Instant` class as of Java 8.

Comment: Date.from(Instant.now().plusSeconds(86400))

Answer (score 612, accepted):

Given a `Date dt` you have several possibilities:

**Solution 1:** You can use the `Calendar` class for that:

```
Date dt = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(dt); 
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
dt = c.getTime();
```

**Solution 2:** You should seriously consider using the **[Joda-Time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)**, because of the various shortcomings of the `Date` class. With Joda-Time you can do the following:

```
Date dt = new Date();
DateTime dtOrg = new DateTime(dt);
DateTime dtPlusOne = dtOrg.plusDays(1);
```

**Solution 3:** With **Java 8** you can also use the new **JSR 310** API (which is inspired by Joda-Time):

```
Date dt = new Date();
LocalDateTime.from(dt.toInstant()).plusDays(1);
```

**Solution 4:** With **org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils** you can do:

```
Date dt = new Date();
dt = DateUtils.addDays(dt, 1)
```

Comment: For Solution 1 (at least), you can also pass it a negative value (such as -1 to get the day prior).

Comment: All solutions support negative offsets, even with their negative counterparts, so instead of `plusDays(1)` one could also use `minusDays(-1)`.

Comment: Solution 3 doesn't end up with a Date.. it ends up with LocalDateTime

Comment: @DanielRikowski If i am adding 1 day to the last day of month in calendar object, the month remains same instead of moving to next month, how to make that work ?

Comment: @DerickDaniel There must be something wrong with your surrounding code. All three solutions correctly wrap at month/year boundaries. Make sure you are calling `getTime()` on your `Calendar` instance, and not `get(...)`. Also note that months are from 0-11, but days are from 1-31.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. And the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the *java.time* classes.

Comment: c.setTime(dt);   line seems unnecessary, as Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  is set to present date and time.

Comment: yes it's worked for me

Answer (score 98):

```
Date today = new Date();
Date tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Date has a constructor using the milliseconds since the UNIX-epoch. the getTime()-method gives you that value. So adding the milliseconds for a day, does the trick. If you want to do such manipulations regularly I recommend to define constants for the values.

Important hint: That is not correct in all cases. Read the WARNING comment, below.

Comment: I would be careful using Date today = new Date(); Date tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); If you are using a `Calendar Timezone` with Daytime Savings, on the changing day from summer to wintertime it will not jump to the next day.

Comment: WARNING!  Adding 1000*60*60*24 milliseconds to a java date will once in a great while add zero days or two days to the original date in the circumstances of leap seconds, daylight savings time and the like.  If you need to be 100% certain only one day is added, this solution is not the one to use.

Comment: You are right. I add the hint to this comment to my answer.

Comment: Downvoting since this is very much the wrong answer, due to both daylight saving time and leap seconds. Use Calendar or Joda time.

Comment: Leap seconds are not an issue in this context, as they are ignored by these date-time libraries: java.util.Date, Joda-Time, and java.time. The real problem with this answer is anomalies such as Daylight Savings Time that result in a day being other than exactly 24 hours long.

Comment: @Eric Leschinski You are assuming that the Date class knows about leap seconds, which it certainly does not appear to despite the woffly comment at the top.  Most systems just adjust the computer clock as happens anyway.  But in any case I cannot see it failing by more than one second.

Comment: @aberglas, You're not thinking through the problem.  You're thinking in terms of wrongness relative to itself, I'm talking about wrongness relative to the system time.  Date is flawless keeper of time with no notion of leap seconds.  But the system time is, so sometimes adding 1000*60*60*24 milliseconds to a Date keeps you on the same day, or takes you forward to the 2nd day relative to the system time.  Date does the perfect thing, and your system clock does the weird thing.  The system time gets the final say on what time it is, so therefore Date's perfect calculation is wrong.

Comment: @ Eric Leschinski I'm pretty sure that System.currentTimeMilliseconds is the number of milliseconds since 1970 MINUS the number of leap seconds added since 1970.  In other words there can be two times with the same currentTimeMilliseconds.  It has to be like that, or it would break almost all software.

Answer (score 36):

I found a simple method to add arbitrary time to a Date object

```
Date d = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86400000)
```

Where:

```
86 400 000 ms = 1 Day  : 24*60*60*1000
 3 600 000 ms = 1 Hour :    60*60*1000
```

Comment: won't handle daylight savings etc. but might be good enough in a pinch :)

Answer (score 28):

As mentioned in the Top answer, since java 8 it is possible to do:

```
Date dt = new Date();
LocalDateTime.from(dt.toInstant()).plusDays(1);
```

but this can sometimes lead to an `DateTimeException` like this:

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 2014-11-29T03:20:10.800Z of type java.time.Instant
```

It is possible to avoid this Exception by simply passing the time zone:

```
LocalDateTime.from(dt.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))).plusDays(1);
```

Comment: As mentioned in comments, this will return a LocalDateDime, not a Date.

Answer (score 23):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) 
         .plusDays( 1 )
```

## java.time

Best to avoid the [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class altogether. But if you must do so, you can convert between the troublesome old legacy date-time classes and the modern java.time classes. Look to new methods added to the old classes.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class, is close to being equivalent to `Date`, both being a moment on the timeline. `Instant` resolves to nanoseconds, while `Date` is milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

You could add a day to this, but keep in mind this in UTC. So you will not be accounting for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time. Specify the unit of time with the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) class.

```
Instant nextDay = instant.plus( 1 , ChronoUnit.DAYS ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to be savvy with time zones, specify a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNextDay = zdt.plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

You can also represent your span-of-time to be added, the one day, as a `Period`.

```
Period p = Period.ofDays( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ).plus( p ) ;
```

You may want the first moment of that next day. Do not assume the day starts at 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean the day may start at another time, such as 01:00:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day on that date in that zone.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plus( p ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = tomorrow.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

**Update:** The Joda-Time library is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes. I am leaving this section intact for history.

## Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library makes this kind of date-time work much easier. The java.util.Date class bundled with Java is notoriously troublesome, and should be avoided.

Here is some example code.

Your java.util.Date is converted to a Joda-Time [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object. Unlike a j.u.Date, a DateTime truly knows its assigned time zone. Time zone is crucial as adding a day to get the same [wall-clock time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) tomorrow might mean making adjustments such as for a 23-hour or 25-hour day in the case of [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) here in the United States. If you specify the [time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), Joda-Time can make that kind of adjustment. After adding a day, we convert the DateTime object back into a java.util.Date object.

```
java.util.Date yourDate = new java.util.Date();

// Generally better to specify your time zone rather than rely on default.
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone timeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Los_Angeles" );
DateTime now = new DateTime( yourDate, timeZone );
DateTime tomorrow = now.plusDays( 1 );
java.util.Date tomorrowAsJUDate = tomorrow.toDate();
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "yourDate: " + yourDate );
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "tomorrow: " + tomorrow );
System.out.println( "tomorrowAsJUDate: " + tomorrowAsJUDate );
```

When run…

```
yourDate: Thu Apr 10 22:57:21 PDT 2014
now: 2014-04-10T22:57:21.535-07:00
tomorrow: 2014-04-11T22:57:21.535-07:00
tomorrowAsJUDate: Fri Apr 11 22:57:21 PDT 2014
```

Comment: scala> java.time.LocalDate.now  => 
res7: java.time.LocalDate = 2018-05-09

scala> java.time.LocalDate.now.plusDays(2)  => 
res9: java.time.LocalDate = 2018-05-11

Comment: @Charlie木匠 ????

Comment: Just comment a couple of usage.

Answer (score 22):

you can use this method after **import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils**:

```
DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), 1);
```

Comment: A redundant right parenthesis at the end.

Answer (score 13):

This will increase any date by exactly one

```
String untildate="2011-10-08";//can take any date in current format    
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );   
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();    
cal.setTime( dateFormat.parse(untildate));    
cal.add( Calendar.DATE, 1 );    
String convertedDate=dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());    
System.out.println("Date increase by one.."+convertedDate);
```

Answer (score 5):

Java 8 Time API:

```
Instant now = Instant.now(); //current date
Instant after= now.plus(Duration.ofDays(300));
Date dateAfter = Date.from(after);
```

Comment: I think this is Java 8 API

Comment: Thanks, of course, fix

Answer (score 4):

use DateTime object obj.Add to add what ever you want day hour and etc.
Hope this works:)

Answer (score 4):

I prefer [joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for date and time arithmetics because it is much better readable:

```
Date tomorrow = now().plusDays(1).toDate();
```

Or

```
endOfDay(now().plus(days(1))).toDate()
startOfDay(now().plus(days(1))).toDate()
```

Comment: and the performance is not important ?
If you must do these computations on many instances, it's very expensive.
Readable is one thing but it should be think in a broader way.

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 LocalDate [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays-long-)

`LocalDate.now().plusDays(1L);`

Answer (score 3):

To make it a touch less java specific, the basic principle would be to convert to some linear date format, julian days, modified julian days, seconds since some epoch, etc, add your day, and convert back.

The reason for doing this is that you farm out the "get the leap day, leap second, etc right' problem to someone who has, with some luck, not mucked this problem up.

I will caution you that getting these conversion routines right can be difficult. There are an amazing number of different ways that people mess up time, the most recent high profile example was MS's Zune.  Dont' poke too much fun at MS though, it's easy to mess up.  It doesn't help that there are multiple different time formats, say, TAI vs TT.

Answer (score 3):

In very special case If you asked to do your own date class, possibly from your Computer Programming Professor; This method would do very fine job.

```
public void addOneDay(){
    int [] months = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    day++;
    if (day> months[month-1]){
        month++;
        day = 1;
        if (month > 12){
            year++;
            month = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a  performance  point of view, the solution is very interresting. +1

Comment: This doesn't work with leap years.

Comment: By putting simple condition you can handle leap year as well. 
```if(year % 4 == 0) {
months[1] =  29;
}```

Answer (score 3):

best thing to use:

```
      long currenTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long oneHourLater = currentTime + TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1l);
```

Similarly, you can add MONTHS, DAYS, MINUTES etc

Answer (score 2):

***Java 1.8 version*** has nice update for data time API.

Here is snippet of code:

```
    LocalDate lastAprilDay = LocalDate.of(2014, Month.APRIL, 30);
    System.out.println("last april day: " + lastAprilDay);
    LocalDate firstMay = lastAprilDay.plusDays(1);
    System.out.println("should be first may day: " + firstMay);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd");
    String formatDate = formatter.format(firstMay);
    System.out.println("formatted date: " + formatDate);
```

***Output:***

```
last april day: 2014-04-30
should be first may day: 2014-05-01
formatted date: 01
```

For more info see Java documentations to this classes:

- [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)
- [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Answer (score 2):

U can try `java.util.Date` library like this way-

```
int no_of_day_to_add = 1;

Date today = new Date();
Date tomorrow = new Date( today.getYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + no_of_day_to_add );
```

Change value of `no_of_day_to_add` as you want.

I have set value of `no_of_day_to_add` to `1` because u wanted only one day to add.

More can be found in [**this documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-int-int-int-).

Answer (score 2):

you want after days find date this code try..

```
public Date getToDateAfterDays(Integer day) {
        Date nowdate = new Date();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(nowdate);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, day);
        return cal.getTime();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I will show you how we can do it in **Java 8**. Here you go:

```
public class DemoDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println("Current date: " + today);

        //add 1 day to the current date
        LocalDate date1Day = today.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println("Date After 1 day : " + date1Day);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Current date: 2016-08-15
Date After 1 day : 2016-08-16
```