# DateTime package

Tags: java

in  which package is DateTime defined

what i need to import ?

Comment: Hey fella, how about putting all of your DateTime questions togather in one place, instead of filing half a dozen near-identical ones?

Comment: Just read your answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005523/how-to-add-one-day-to-a-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class from [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), it is under the `org.joda.time` package.

It does not come with the standard Java distribution, so it will need to be downloaded from the [Joda Time site](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).