# How to get last month/year in java?

Tags: java, calendar, java-time

How do I find out the last month and its year in Java?

e.g. If today is Oct. 10 2012, the result should be `Month = 9` and `Year = 2012`. If today is Jan. 10 2013, the result should be `Month = 12` and `Year = 2012`.

Comment: Look at the API documentation of `java.util.Calendar`. Or make your life easier by using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: If using java.util.Calendar be careful with the id's of months. January is zero not one.

Comment: Refere this Example : http://www.java-examples.com/add-or-substract-months-current-date-using-java-calendar

Comment: Jesper and Tinman, I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `YearMonth` or `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Your solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005523/how-to-add-one-day-to-a-date) but instead of addition you need to use subtraction

```
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
```

Then you can call [getter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) on the `Calendar` to acquire proper fields

```
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // beware of month indexing from zero
int year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 37):

## java.time

Using `java.time` framework built into Java 8:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); // 2015-11-24
LocalDate earlier = now.minusMonths(1); // 2015-10-24

earlier.getMonth(); // java.time.Month = OCTOBER
earlier.getMonth.getValue(); // 10
earlier.getYear(); // 2015
```

Comment: What if it's March 30 and you substract one "month" with this?

Comment: For 28..31 of March it returns 28 February, so it answers the original question.

Comment: java.time api never ceases to impress..

Answer (score 12):

Use [Joda Time Library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net). It is very easy to handle date, time, calender and locale with it and it will be integrated to java in version 8.

`DateTime#minusMonths` method would help you get previous month.

```
DateTime month = new DateTime().minusMonths (1);
```

Comment: **Update:** The *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance-mode. Its creator Stephen Colebourne went on to lead its successor, the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 10):

you can use the Calendar class to do so:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
```

This prints : `2012.09.10 11:01` for actual date `2012.10.10 11:01`

Comment: **Update:** These terrible classes are now obsolete. Supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310, built into Java 8 and later, and available for Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest & least error prone approach is... Use Calendar's roll() method. Like this:

```
    c.roll(Calendar.MONTH, false);
```

the roll method takes a boolean, which basically means roll the month up(true) or down(false)?

Comment: This doesn't roll the year. The year will not change if you use this.

Comment: Downvoted as this is incorrect, like Gergy008 said. In 99 % of cases (and especially the one OP asked), this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

## `YearMonth` class

You can use the [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class, and its [`minusMonths`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html#minusMonths(long)) method.

```
YearMonth lastMonth = YearMonth.now().minusMonths(1);
```

Calling [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html#toString()) gives you output in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: `yyyy-mm`

You can access the parts, the year and the month. You may choose to use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum object, or a mere `int` value 1-12 for the month.

```
int year = lastMonth.getYear() ;
int month = lastMonth.getMonthValue() ;
Month monthEnum = lastMonth.getMonth() ;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
private static String getPreviousMonthDate(Date date){
    final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
    cal.setTime(date);  
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

    Date preMonthDate = cal.getTime();  
    return format.format(preMonthDate);
}


private static String getPreToPreMonthDate(Date date){
    final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
    cal.setTime(date);  
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);  
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);  
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);  

    Date preToPreMonthDate = cal.getTime();  
    return format.format(preToPreMonthDate);
}
```

Comment: Please avoid giving code-only answers. Try to explain how your code solves OP's problem.

Comment: Ohhh sorry i will try my best..and next time i will provide proper explanation david thanks for good suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware that month is zero based so when you do the getMonth you will need to add 1. In the example below we have to add 1 to Januaray as 1 and not 0

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2011, 2, 1);
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    assertEquals(1, month);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get by using the LocalDate class.

For Example:

1. To get last month date:

   LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1);
2. To get starting date of last month

   LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());

Similarly for Year:

1. To get last year date:

   LocalDate.now().minusYears(1);
2. To get starting date of last year :

   LocalDate.now().minusYears(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear());

Answer (score -3):

Here's the code snippet.I think it works.

```
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      SimpleDateFormat simpleMonth=new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM YYYY");
      cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
      System.out.println(simpleMonth.format(prevcal.getTime()));
```