# Calculating one year ago today

Tags: java, jodatime

How do I build an `Instant` object whose value is one year ago today?

For example if right now is `2015-12-20T11:53` I want an `Instant` object containing `2014-12-20T11:53`.

`Instant` has a `minus` function that receives a `Duration` but `Duration` doesn't have a `years` function. There is a class called `Period` that has a `Period.years` function but running `Period.years(1).toStandardDuration()` throws the following exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot convert to Duration as this period contains years and years vary in length

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get previous month and years in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814504/how-to-get-previous-month-and-years-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `DateTime.minusYears(int years);` method.

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html

Comment: What object has a minusYears method?

Comment: `DateTime` has a minusYears method. You can get a `DateTime` from an `Instant` by calling `toDateTime`.

Comment: The OP is using Java 8 date time classes not JodaTime (as far as I can tell)

Comment: @munyengm: have you checked the tags he added to his post?