# Get current date + 1 day for FQL query

Tags: java, android, date, facebook-fql

I need the get the current date like "yyyy-mm-dd" so not the hours and minutes.
And I need the current day 24hours futher so 1 day futher.

I need it in my fql query this is my query:

```
String FQL + = .... AND start_time<'" + startTime + "' AND start_time>'" + endTime + "'  LIMIT 25"
```

I'm doing this with this code but it doesn't work:

```
Date myDate = new Date();
            Date endTime = new Date(myDate.getTime() + 86400000L);
            Date startTime = new Date(myDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Basically a duplicate of question [How to add one day to a date?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1005523/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `startTime` < `endTime`

because

```
Date startTime = new Date(myDate.getTime());
Date endTime = new Date(myDate.getTime() + 86400000L);
```

how can the expression

```
 X<'" + startTime + "' AND X>'" + endTime + "'
```

ever by true?

```
 X < startTime                                      X > endTime 
---------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------
                       startTime               endTime
```

I replaced it with X to better distinguish between start_time and startTime

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instance.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd");
String startTime = sf.format(calendar.getTime());
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
String endTime = sf.format(calendar.getTime());
```

As Rene rightly points out, `start_time` needs to be GREATER than `startTime` (`start_time > startTime`) and SMALLER than your `endTime` (`start_time < endTime`).

Let me also point you to [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), which makes handling of dates much more comfortable. But for your purpose, the code above is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.Calendar

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); // adds 1 day
calendar.getTime(); // returns the Date
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

edit: 
I read it as if the question was only about the format, but what René Link pointed out is right: Your query can never yield any results.

With java.util.Date it's something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date today = new Date(now);
Date tomorrow = new Date(now + 86400000); // 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
System.out.println("Today: " + dateFormat.format(today) + 
                   "\nTomorrow: " + dateFormat.format(tomorrow));
```

With java.sql.Date it becomes slightly simpler:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date today = new Date(now);
Date tomorrow = new Date(now + 86400000);
System.out.println("Today: " + today + "\nTomorrow: " + tomorrow);
```

And maybe you might want to use `java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` instead of the `System.currentTimeMillis()` to create the first date. You then simply have to get the first date's time in millis to add the 86400000 to the second date.