# How to compute calendar date?

Tags: java, date

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
```

If I want to know the date after 3 days from "cal", is there a way to compute that? Thanks. Can the add(int field, int amount) method do that?

Comment: Before asking it is always a good idea to search the site (or the whole internet) and also read the official documentation, otherwise you might find your question gets downvoted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add one day to a date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005523/how-to-add-one-day-to-a-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you can get the date from a `Calendar` object:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar()
Date d;
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
d = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then yes. Using [`Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH)

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
```