# Unable to get only the day of date from the date format?

Tags: java, date, date-format

How to get the date from the date format

> dd/MM/yyyy

Example:

> 04/05/2015

I only need  the date as `04`.

Here is code snippet:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = new Date(); 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

***How to solve this issue?***

Comment: Take a look at the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005523/how-to-add-one-day-to-a-date

Comment: @ShivaRavi does your question solved?

Answer (score 2):

Use `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change `DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");` to `DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");`
or use `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change pattern which shows to you desired data format:

> DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");

instead of

> DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

**UPDATE:**

***Java 1.8*** has updated data and time API.

Here is snippet of code which I checked:

```
    LocalDate lastAprilDay = LocalDate.of(2014, Month.APRIL, 30);
    System.out.println("last april day: " + lastAprilDay);
    LocalDate firstMay = lastAprilDay.plusDays(1);
    System.out.println("should be first may day: " + firstMay);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd");
    String formatDate = formatter.format(firstMay);
    System.out.println("formatted date: " + formatDate);
```

***Output:***

```
last april day: 2014-04-30
should be first may day: 2014-05-01
formatted date: 01
```

For more info see Java documentations to this classes:

- [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)
- [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: I have tried that too.. in other scenario where i have to increment the date its not working proper (Eg: April month has 30 days if i increment one day the current day is displayed as 31 instead 1st may ) kindly suggest how to over cum this ??

Comment: @ShivaRavi Which version of **JDK** have you used?

Comment: @ShivaRavi for date manipulation, you must use Calendar class, not Date class.

Comment: @nazar_art i am using jdk-8u40-windows-x64

Comment: @nazar_art : Thanks  a lot.. i will try this i let you know :)

Comment: @ShivaRavi To be sure that you are using exactly `JDK 1.8` at your ***IDE***.

Comment: @ShivaRavi it's kind of you "accept" the answer that resolved your issue, cheers!