# Java obtaining a timestamp from a date value - "Timestamp" is not a resolved type?

Tags: java, jdbc, timestamp

I am new to `Java` development - and I am trying to convert a date value - "2017-09-14" to a timestamp like "1355759900000".

I've tried to get a conversion like this

```
Date starting_time = (Date) obj.get("assessment date");
java.sql.Timestamp timeStampDate = new Timestamp(starting_time.getCreatedTime().getTime());
System.out.println("Today is " +timeStampDate);
```

but it tells me `Timestamp` is not a resolved type.

I also need to do a calculation where I create an end date -- a day in the future from the start date.

---

got it working after this

```
//get start time date
Date starting_time = (Date) obj.get("assessment date");
//get start time date

//get end time date
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(starting_time); 
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
java.util.Date ending_time = c.getTime();
//get end time date

long starting_time_timestamp = new Timestamp(starting_time.getTime()).getTime();
long ending_time_timestamp = new Timestamp(ending_time.getTime()).getTime();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating timestamp:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

[1 day in future](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1005550/6598759)

Answer (score 0):

How are you converting "2017-09-14" to a timestamp like "1355759900000".

I did not get this one, but here is the code that you can use.

Output is :

Today is 2015-03-31 00:00:00.0

String timestamp: 31032015000000

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String str="2015-03-31";
        Date starting_time = Date.valueOf(str);
        java.sql.Timestamp timeStampDate = new Timestamp(starting_time.getTime());
        System.out.println("Today is " + timeStampDate);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
        System.out.println("String timestamp: "+sdf.format(timeStampDate));
    }
}
```