# Get tomorrow date of a special date

Tags: java, android, date

I have this Java `Date` `"Fri Oct 26 19:45:00 GMT+02:00 2018"`. How to get the day after that day? So I need this: `"Sa Oct 27 19:45:00 GMT+02:00 2018"`. 
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
long ms = yourDate.getTime();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(ms);
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
long nextDayInMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();
Date nextDate=new Date(nextDayInMillis);
```

Comment: You can use `setTiime(yourDate)` instead of `setTimeInMillis(yourDate.getTime())`. See also the duplicated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005523/how-to-add-one-day-to-a-date

Comment: @slartidan that's much easier to write this answer instead of search this duplicated question on the internet. And of course, you can mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Ah okay, and to get the day in a week, for example, it would be `c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);`?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Ok, when my logic is right that should work...But how to do this when I want to get the Day one month later?

Comment: @marcelo.wdrb, of course, you can. You can use the other constants. For your case use `c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);`

Comment: Marking a question as duplicate will help to create a growing overview of different possibilities with all their up- and downsides. It is usually much more helpful to link to an existing, great question, than to try to spontaneously come up with an answer.