# cannot resolve method plusDays Java

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to use a for loop through iterate through a range of dates, and I was going to increment the start date using plusDays, but I get "cannot resolve method plusDays in Date".
Here is my code:

```
   for(Date date = finalSD; date.before(finalED); date = date.plusDays(1)){
            myBookings.put(finalSD,fac);
        }
```

Comment: `plusDays` is a method of `LocalDate`, not `Date`.

Comment: `java.util.Date` does not have this function, you must switch to LocalDate from `java.time`

Comment: @Mureinik is there a method for Date then, since i want to increment from a given start date?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also `LocalDate` is better suited for a start date. And no, there is no such method for `Date`. You will need one conversion or another, and I recommend the conversion to some type from java.time.

Comment: @OleV.V. yeah changed everything to LocalDate type and managed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea this all about time zones etc. That is the reason why it's so complicated

```
    Date finalSD = new Date();
    Date finalED = new Date();
    LocalDate localFinalSD = LocalDate.from(finalSD.toInstant());
    LocalDate localFinalED = LocalDate.from(finalED.toInstant());
    for(LocalDate date = localFinalSD; date.isBefore(localFinalED); date =  date .plusDays(1)){
        myBookings.put(finalSD,fac);
    }
```

Comment: I’d bewre of `LocalDate.from(finalSD.toInstant())`. Not in all time zones will it give you the day that you think is in the `Date`. I suggest `finalSD.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()` instead. Similar for end date. Otherwise a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Date` is not `java.time.LocalDate`

`java.util.Date` does not have a `plusDays(1L)` function:

So if you work with Date you can increment using :

```
Date dt = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(dt); 
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
dt = c.getTime();
```

or you just use java.time as :

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plus(1) ;
```

take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005523/how-to-add-one-day-to-a-date)