# Kotlin convert string to date and take one day before

Tags: date, kotlin

I have a problem. I have a date in String f.eg "2021-05-06", and now i need to take one day before (2021-05-05). Here I'm making date from String but I cannot take one day before. Any tips?

```
val date = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(currentDate)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java). The same way a day is added here, you can also do minus

Comment: Your date is in "yyyy-MM-dd" so parsing with a different format will not work..

Comment: @Alex.T this is not my question, but I will check it.

Comment: @RobCo ooo my mistake, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
val date = LocalDate.parse("2021-05-06", formatter).minusDays(1)
println(date)
```

**Output:**

> 2021-05-05

Answer (score 2):

If working with `LocalDate` is fine you could do

```
var date = LocalDate.parse("2021-05-06")
date = date.minusDays(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

By analogy with similar questions in Java (there was addition, but we can perform subtraction), we can get the following piece of code:

```
val date = LocalDate.parse(currentDate)
val newDate = date.minusDays(1)
```

[First similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005523/how-to-add-one-day-to-a-date)

[Second similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)