# How to subtract 45 days from from the current sysdate

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyone know a simple way using java calendar to subtract X days to a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212321/anyone-know-a-simple-way-using-java-calendar-to-subtract-x-days-to-a-date)

Hi ,

Could anybody please tell me how can we subtract 45 days from the current sysdate ??

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the SYSDATE function in Oracle PL/SQL?

Comment: I am refering to system date of windows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Calendar class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR , -45);
```

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of [How to subtract X days from a date using Java calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212321/anyone-know-a-simple-way-using-java-calendar-to-subtract-x-days-to-a-date).  You can use the add function with negative days, e.g., add(Calendar.DATE, -5).

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html for the fine details.

Comment: please try to share links to the most updated docs in the future (Java 6) :)

Comment: That is outright embarrassing.  Thanks MByD.

Comment: so many people reminded me to do that here before, just keeping the tradition :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html). :-)

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

DateTime dt = new DateTime().minusDays(45);

// Convert to java.util.Date
Date d = dt.toDate();
```