# How can we check if the current system date is of 1 Month Back

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to subtract 45 days from from the current sysdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086162/how-to-subtract-45-days-from-from-the-current-sysdate)

Hi I am getting the current system date by using

```
Java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
```

How can i check whether my Date is One month Before date

For example if today is May 22 2011

How can i check if the date is of April 22 2011 ??

Comment: what date? if you use `new Date()`, it will **always** be today.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). Its [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class has a [minusMonth](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minusMonths%28int%29)-method. Use this to get the date from one month ago and then compare. See the Joda-API for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(theGivenDate);

Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

if ( (cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)) &&
     (cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH)) &&
     (cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) ) {
  System.out.println("Given date " 
    + theGivenDate + " is exactly one month ago from today");
}
```

Comment: What about the case where the current date is in January?

Comment: @Stephen It will roll back into December of the previous year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Joda DateTime [http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html] for this.

DateTime has a method minusMonths(int months), and then you can convert Joda DateTime to java.util.Date

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that many dates will *never* be "one month before today" according to your definition for month as "calendar month"? For example, since June has only 30 days, the condition will never be true for May 31st.

You may want to change your definition to that commonly used by banks for purposes like calculating interest and deposit terms: a month is considered to be exactly 30 days, independent of calendar dates. So "one month after" May 31st would be June 30th.