# How to subtract x amount of days from todays date

Tags: android

I need to count back 90 days, 120 days and 160 days for a few items. How would I code this?
I keep finding java code but that brings up errors when I am developing for android.

I need to take todays date and subtract the x amount of days and have it result be displayed on the screen nothing else. Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about the errors and the code that produced them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to subtract X days from a date using Java calendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212321/how-to-subtract-x-days-from-a-date-using-java-calendar)

Answer (score 35):

You should use the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class :

```
//Calendar set to the current date 
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
//rollback 90 days
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -90);
//now the date is 90 days back
Log.i("MyApp","90 days ago:"+calendar.getTime().toString());
```

Comment: roll() is adding to fields, not substracting. But it is not correct, because it does not change larger fields. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 11):

Use the Calendar object...

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -90); //etc
```

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .minusDays( 90 )
```

## java.time

Other answers here are outdated. The modern way is with java.time classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

You can then add or subtract days.

```
LocalDate ago090 = today.minusDays( 90 ) ;
LocalDate ago120 = today.minusDays( 120 ) ;
LocalDate ago160 = today.minusDays( 160 ) ;
```

To generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format of YYYY-MM-DD, call `toString`. For other formats, search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter` class to see many examples and discussions.

```
String output = ago120.toString() ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `Calendar` class to achieve what you want: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html.

You can then call on your calendar object with the current date `.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -90);` and so on.