# How to subtract n days from current date in java?

Tags: java, date

I want to subtract n days from the current date in Java.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You don't have to use Calendar. You can just play with timestamps :

```
Date d = initDate();//intialize your date to any date 
Date dateBefore = new Date(d.getTime() - n * 24 * 3600 * 1000 l ); //Subtract n days
```

**UPDATE**
DO NOT FORGET TO ADD "l" for long by the end of 1000.

Please consider the below WARNING:

Adding `1000*60*60*24` milliseconds to a java date will once in a great while add zero days or two days to the original date in the circumstances of leap seconds, daylight savings time and the like. If you need to be 100% certain only one day is added, this solution is not the one to use.

Comment: Thank you Houcem Berrayana!!!

Comment: If `n` is large (> 24) you need to make sure the value is evaluated as a `long` as the value will be too large for a `int`

Comment: d.getTime() returns already a long value. So adding a long + int gives a long

Comment: The clean way is the @Korgen way, not this

Comment: But somebody says even this is not always safe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/212334/948268

Comment: Be careful, this may not work, for instance when dealing with leapyears: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1006388/32453

Comment: This way does not handle Daylight Saving Time.  If you cross a date where the time changes, then then the time will be off by +- 1 hour.

Comment: Good enough for creating random test data +1

Answer (score 52):

this will subtract ten days of the current date (before Java 8):

```
int x = -10;
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, x);
Date tenDaysAgo = cal.getTime();
```

If you're using Java 8 you can make use of the new Date & Time API (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html):

```
LocalDate tenDaysAgo = LocalDate.now().minusDays(10);
```

For converting the new to the old types and vice versa see: [Converting between java.time.LocalDateTime and java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date)

Comment: What is difference between `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR` and `Calendar.DATE` ? Both gives me Result.

Answer (score 8):

I found this perfect solution and may useful, You can directly get in format as you want:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -90); // I just want date before 90 days. you can give that you want.

SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // you can specify your format here...
Log.d("DATE","Date before 90 Days: " + s.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis())));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## for future use find day of the week ,deduct day and display the deducted day using date.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

String[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date dt1 = format1.parse("20/10/2013");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(dt1);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
long diff = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime() ;
System.out.println(dayOfWeek);

switch (dayOfWeek) {

case 6:
    System.out.println(days[dayOfWeek - 1]);
    break;
case 5:

    System.out.println(days[dayOfWeek - 1]);
    break;      
case 4:
    System.out.println(days[dayOfWeek - 1]);
    break;
case 3:

    System.out.println(days[dayOfWeek - 1]);
    break;
case 2:
    System.out.println(days[dayOfWeek - 1]);
    break;
case 1:

    System.out.println(days[dayOfWeek - 1]);

     diff = diff -(dt1.getTime()- 3 );
     long valuebefore = dt1.getTime();
     long valueafetr = dt1.getTime()-2;
     System.out.println("DATE IS befor subtraction :"+valuebefore);
     System.out.println("DATE IS after subtraction :"+valueafetr);

     long x= dt1.getTime()-(2 * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
     System.out.println("Deducted date to find firday is - 2 days form Sunday :"+new Date((dt1.getTime()-(2*24*3600*1000))));
     System.out.println("DIffrence from now on is :"+diff);
        if(diff > 0) {

            diff = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
            System.out.println("Diff"+diff);
            System.out.println("Date is Expired!"+(dt1.getTime() -(long)2));
        }

    break;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As @Houcem Berrayana say

If you would like to use `n>24` then you can use the code like:

```
Date dateBefore = new Date((d.getTime() - n * 24 * 3600 * 1000) - n * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
```

Suppose you want to find last 30 days date, then you'd use:

```
Date dateBefore = new Date((d.getTime() - 24 * 24 * 3600 * 1000) - 6 * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
```

Comment: I don't see the value added by this Answer. [a] It repeats the math given in the [accepted Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10796111/642706). [b] Provides a poor solution, ignoring time zones and Daylight Saving Time. If I am missing the point, then perhaps you should add more discussion to the Answer.