# How to add or subtract 3 days from currentdate in java?

Tags: java, datetime

I need to subtract 3 days from current date and need to store that in Date variable?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? Did you take a look at [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) by any chance?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005523/how-to-add-one-day-to-a-date?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795997/how-to-subtract-n-days-from-current-date-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Also consider using Joda Time for all your date/time needs - it's much cleaner than `Date`/`Calendar`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212321/how-to-subtract-x-days-from-a-date-using-java-calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this

```
Calender c = Calender.getInstance();

c.add(DAY_OF_MONTH,3);

c.add(DAY_OF_MONTH,-3);

Date d = c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 2):

Pull the milliseconds-since-epoch value out, subtract three days of milliseconds from it, shove it into a new Date object.

```
public static final long ONE_DAY_MILLIS = 86400 * 1000;

Date now = new Date();
Date then = new Date(now.getTime() - (3 * ONE_DAY_MILLIS));
```