# How to read emails from today in outlook

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

I am trying to read the emails i have received today only using the javax.mail api.

```java
Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

ReceivedDateTerm term = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.EQ,new Date(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

Message[] messages = emailFolder.search(term);
```

The above code does not return any emails even though i do have in my inbox.

Comment: Do you have a connection established already to your mailbox? How are you connecting to it?

Comment: What is `new Date(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` intended to do?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `Date` constructor takes in a `long` which represents the milliseconds from January 1st, 1970. However, `Calender.DAY_OF_MONTH` seems to only return an integer representing the day of the month. I would recommend using something such as `System.currentTimeMillis()` to derive the date in millis.

References:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--

[What's the difference between adding DAY_OF_MONTH or DAY_OF_YEAR to a Calendar object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065198/whats-the-difference-between-adding-day-of-month-or-day-of-year-to-a-calendar-o)

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I do *not* know JavaMail, and don’t understand the exact behavior of `ReceivedDateTerm`. But I do know date-time handling. If the goal is determine the first moment of today, read on.

## First moment of day

Your date-time handling is incorrect.

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Getting the current date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Determine the first moment. Not necessarily the time 00:00:00 as some dates in some zones start at another time such as 01:00:00.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = today.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Extract an `Instant` to adjust into UTC. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

The [constructor for `ReceivedDateTerm`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/mail/search/ReceivedDateTerm.html#ReceivedDateTerm-int-java.util.Date-) takes a `java.util.Date` object, having not yet been updated to the modern *java.time* framework.

Convert from our modern `Instant` to the terrible and misnamed legacy class `java.util.Date`.

```
Date d = Date.from( instant ) ;
```

Pass `d` to your JavaMail code as the starting moment for your search.

Comment: This is still returning no emails :(.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
ReceivedDateTerm term = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.EQ,new Date(Calendar.getTime()));
```

or

```
SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat( "MM/dd/yy" );
java.util.Date dDate = format.parse("01/01/19");
SearchTerm st = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.EQ,dDate );
```