# how to get the timestamp of previous dates in java?

Tags: java, timestamp

In my shopping cart application, I am storing all the purchase dates in timestamp.

Suppose, I want to get the timestamp of purchase date n days before (n is configurable). How will I get it using java?

example: something like 
 purchasedateBefore5days = currentTimestamp_in_days - 5;
I am getting current timestamp using

```
long currentTimestamp = Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
```

How can i subtract n days from it. I am a beginner. Please help on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `Calendar` class:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -5);
long fiveDaysAgo = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Is it possible to calculate 5 day before and after at the same time with single instance of Calendar?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class in Java , use its [set()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,int%29) method to add/subtract the required number of days from the [Calendar.DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DATE) field.

To subtract `n` days from today , Use `c.get(Calendar.DATE)-n`. Sample code :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(c.getTime()); // Tue Jun 18 17:07:45 IST 2013
c.set(Calendar.DATE, c.get(Calendar.DATE)-5);
System.out.println(c.getTime()); // Thu Jun 13 17:07:45 IST 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Date d = initDate();//intialize your date to any date 
Date dateBefore = new Date(d.getTime() - n * 24 * 3600 * 1000 ); //Subtract n days
```

Also [possible duplicate .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212321/how-to-subtract-x-days-from-a-date-using-java-calendar)

Answer (score 1):

That `currentTimestamp`  must be passed to a Calendar instance.
from Calendar you can subtract X days.
Get the milliseconds from calendar and is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can play aorund with the following code snippet, to form it the way you want:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -5);

Date date = c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -5);
```

using [Java.util.Calendar Class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_calendar.htm)

**Calendar.DATE**

`This is the field number for get and set indicating the day of the month. , to subtract 5 days from the current time of the calendar, you can achieve it by calling.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);

cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.get(Calendar.DATE)-5);

java.util.Date date1 = cal.getTime();

System.out.println(date1);
```